Eclipse & Nodejs Enide 2015: Nodeclipse NOT available
I would like to use NODEJS with Eclipse, possibly with debugging features.
I found many webpages suggesting to use Enide2015 or Nodeclipse
With Eclipse 2024,3 & 2024.6, I tried to install Enide and/or Nodeclipse from the Marketplace, BUT the installer stops, warning that Enide2015  (and nodeclipse) are NOT available.

Are the two projects too old and closed, or there is a way to find and install them with Eclipse 2024,x?
Is Eclipse a good platform to code&debug with nodeJS? Which plugin are you using to make it work?


This? According to the Marketplace item (when you click on the download icon), the latest supported Eclipse version is 2021-03. A comment on the Marketplace item by Laura V recommends Eclipse Wild Web Developer as an alternative that can be used in more recent Eclipse versions.
